Is one allowed to volunteer in a food pantry affiliated with a church?
We all know that going in a church is assur. But what about going into a building associated with a church? E.g. let's say a place like Rauschenbusch Metro Ministries, which appears to just offer community services but with a blatant affiliation to a church. Is one permitted to participate in volunteer activities under their banner?

If "affiliation" were an issue, you could not enter the house of a church-going Christian.  That is not the case.

I'm shocked that this is a legit question... "is one allowed to ease suffering?"

@Wyrsa As a Jew I'm compelled by Torah Law to die rather than lend credence to idolatry. I don't care what a church is doing or how good it is - if I'm lending credence to Christianity by participating, I won't be.

@Yehuda Yes, and that is all well and good, but wouldn't helping feed the hungry simply be an unquestionable mitzvah and an act of Chesed? Helping those who are hungry seems impossible to object to from my perspective. You're not worshiping an idol, you're not supporting another religion, you are helping the needy. Which would be Tzedakah right?

@Wyrsa If helping the needy comes alongside giving credence to idolatry, it's not worth doing. Let me give you a comparison you can probably relate to better - if helping the needy required you to murder/rape your child, would you want to help the needy under those conditions, or would you find another way to do chesed? I choose those examples because they represent the other two of the three Cardinal Sins of Judaism: Murder, illicit relations, and idolatry. A Jew must give up their life before violating any of those three.

@Wyrsa Putting aside the issue that Judaism views mitzvos that come about due to sin as "fruit of the poisonous tree." It's a principle known as מצוה הבאה בעבירה - mitzvah haba'ah ba'aveirah - and those mitzvos are viewed as illegitimate.

That's interesting to hear, the poisonous tree makes sense. Your example seems over the top though. If helping the needy meant I had to work with "minor attracted persons" and "murderers" I would still help the needy. My association with "tax collectors" is not something forbidden, my actions should encourage them to improve by example. (That is all christian though) So from the Jewish perspective, to work with such people is somehow making their unrelated actions more "Legit"? (Your example to me would be like if you had to go attend a church service to be permitted to help feed the hungry)

@Wyrsa That's precisely the basis of my question. How definitionally related to a church does a charity have to be before it constitutes an impermissible association?
